# click handler gets called immediately for document using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, event-handling, click

```
menuClick: function () {
            var _this = this;
            var clickNamespace = 'click.menu-item' + this.get('currentComponentIndex');

            Ember.$(document).on(clickNamespace, function (event) {
                if (!Ember.$(_this.getSourceFromEvent(event)).closest(_this.$('.menu-item')).length)    {
                    Ember.$(document).off(clickNamespace);
                    _this.set('isSubmenuVisible', false);       
                }
            });
            this.set('isSubmenuVisible', true);
        },
```

Whenever there is a click on a menu-button a click handler is registered and when the click happens anywhere else in the body the click handler is de-registered.
When i do Ember.$('body').on it works perfectly fine but when i do Ember.$(document).on, the handler is called immediately along with handler registration. The handler is not called after clicking but immediately when the registration happens! What is the reason?

Comment: My guess would be that ember doesn't handle event delegation gracefully.

Comment: but ember is not handling. its jquery!

Comment: Uh, sure. I think jQuery cannot handle event attachments during the execution of an event handler, the event propagates to the new handler and triggers it immediately.

Comment: @Bergi Could you please elaborate? If that is the case how come its working for 'body'?

Comment: I guess because there are no `click` handlers installed on `body` yet but there are on `document`. Native DOM does not trigger listeners that are installed during the event propagation, but jQuery does only use them once iirc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have attached the menuClick using a $('body').on("click", ".menu-item", menuClick) or something similar.

Now when menuClick is called, and you bind the $(document).on(... in your question, the event is eventually going to bubble up to your document, trigger a click and call the handler you just attached.

If you bind to $('body').on(..., the handler gets attached, but since the event has already bubbled to the body, it is not triggered again as the event bubbles up.

You could just add a event.stopPropagation() in your menuClick to stop the event from bubbling up.

Comment: this sounds good IF i have already registered for 'body'. let me check and get back : ). i am pretty sure i have not registered for body separately anywhere else